# Android: Convert an anonymous account to a Google or Facebook account

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, google-cloud-firestore

I've been following this tutorial: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/anonymous-auth

My app enable users to login anonymously as a Firebase anonymous user. But I also have a sign in flow through [Multiple Auth Provider](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/account-linking). Now my users have some saved data according to their firebase auto generated anonymous id. So, for people who had previously stored data as anonymous user, I wish to transfer that to new logged in data.

My data is mapped with dataItem against userid/uid.

This is my code which I'm using to login users:

```
    private void linkAnonymousAccount(AuthCredential credential) {
        mAuth.getCurrentUser().linkWithCredential(credential)
            .addOnCompleteListener((Executor) this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "linkWithCredential:success");
                        FirebaseUser user = task.getResult().getUser();
                        goToMainActivity();
                    } else {
                        Log.w(TAG, "linkWithCredential:failure", task.getException());
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.getInstance(), "Authentication failed.",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            });
}
```

This is the code to generate credentials:

```
if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
        IdpResponse response = IdpResponse.fromResultIntent(data);
        currentUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
        if (response != null && response.getUser().getProviderId().equals(FacebookAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID)) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                try {
                    String scope = "oauth2:" + Scopes.EMAIL + " " + Scopes.PROFILE;
                    accessToken = AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken().toString();
                    Log.d(TAG, "accessToken:" + accessToken);

                    AuthCredential credential = FacebookAuthProvider.getCredential(accessToken);
                    userEmail = currentUser.getEmail();
                    userName = currentUser.getDisplayName();
                    linkAnonymousAccount(credential);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        } else if (response != null && response.getUser().getProviderId().equals(GoogleAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID)){
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                try {
                        String scope = "oauth2:" + Scopes.EMAIL + " " + Scopes.PROFILE;
                        accessToken = mAuth.getAccessToken(true).toString();
                        Log.d(TAG, "accessToken:" + accessToken);
                        AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider
                                .getCredential(accessToken, null);
                        userEmail = currentUser.getEmail();
                        userName = currentUser.getDisplayName();
                        linkAnonymousAccount(credential);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
              }
        }
 }
```

> P.S. Firestore Collection
>
> Firestore autogenerated id -> (name, uid)
>
> Example:
>
> abcdelfj -> (himanshu, xcvdf)

Comment: What data are you referring to? Anything in database or something?

Comment: Data in Firestore collections

Comment: Can you please share a screenshot on how that data looks like ?

Comment: Please edit your question and add your database structure as a screenshot and show us what is the exact data you need to transfer.  Please respond with @AlexMamo

Comment: Added. I am querying on uid.